# Get values from JSP with Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, jsp, model-view-controller

I have Spring project generated by maven and my JSP insert.jsp in */target/m2e-wtp/web-resources* and it looks like this:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Library</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Insert record</h1>
    <form action="InsertBook" method="POST">
        Title: <input type="text" name="title"/><br>
        Author: <input type="text" name="author"/><br>
        Category: <select name="category">
            <c:forEach var="cat" items="${categories}">
                <option>${cat}</option>
            </c:forEach>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="insert"/>
    </form>
</body>
```

The Controler is located in */src/main/java/com/mypackage/web/InsertBook.java* and code is here:

```
package com.mypackage.web;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class InsertBook
 */
public class InsertBook extends HttpServlet {
@Override
   protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
     logger.info("GOT IT.");
   }
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    if (request.getCharacterEncoding() == null) {
        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    }

    String title = request.getParameter("title");
    String author = request.getParameter("author");
    logger.info("GOT IT.");


    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("register");
    rd.forward(request, response);
}
}
```

And servlet-context.xml code here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven />

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" /> 

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.mypackage.web" />
<resources location="/resources/**" mapping="/src/webapp/resources"/>
```

I got the message form tomcat server, when trying to access this JSP:

```
INFO : com.mypackage.web.HomeController - Welcome home! The client locale is cs.
WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request         with URI [/web/<c:url value=] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'
```

Could anybody please show me, how to access the values filled in to the form in JSP via the controller and then print them out - for example via logger?

Comment: You should not be implementing your own Servlets if you want to use SpringMVC.  Everything gets routed through Spring's own dispatcher servlet.  I don't know how to answer your question with writing an entire "getting started with Spring MVC tutorial" of which the internet has plenty.  Spring's PetClinic example application is a good place to start.

Comment: Ah so...It seems I haven't understood, how Spring works..thanks for comment ;)

Answer (score 1):

This might be late in your needs here, but you should be implementing a Controller and using the Spring DispatcherServlet that you define in your web.xml. If you continue to use the xml application context configuration, you then define your controller beans and other beans (e.g. DAOs, Services, or other Components) in the applicationContext file along with items like URLViewResolver. (Spring 3 also allows for a Java configuration method for the appication context).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>SpringMVC</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

...

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<bean id="defaultMyDatasource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${myDriverClass}" />
    <property name="url" value="${myURL}" />
    <property name="username" value="${myLogin}" />
    <property name="password" value="${myPassword}" />
</bean>
 ...
```

Thing is to let Spring (and any ORM that you decide to use) to do simplify your Java code. I would recommend reviewing the tutorials provided by [ViralPatel](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/tutorial-spring-3-mvc-introduction-spring-mvc-framework/) or the examples in the Spring in Action book from Craig Walls.  These have helped several of our newer developers gain a better understanding of Spring.